# Disable other options (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, radio-button

```
<p><label><input type="radio" name="group1" /> one</label></p>
<p><label><input type="radio" name="group1" /> two</label></p>
<p><label><input type="radio" name="group1" /> three</label></p>
```

When one of the radio input is selected, I'd like to completely *disable* others. I tried with the jquery siblings selector but it works only if all selects are in the same parent element.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(':radio[name=group1]').change(function() {
    $(':radio[name=group1]:not(:checked)').attr('disabled','disabled');
});​
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VLPcq/2/)

Or a more dynamic approach:

```
$(':radio').change(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    $(':radio[name='+name+']:not(:checked)').attr('disabled','disabled');
});​
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VLPcq/1/)